# Connect Raspberry PI to internet with wifi smartphone tethering while also accesing Rpi's webserver from the same phone

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

The title is self explanatory. I wan't a standalone system in a raspberry pi that only access to the internet when you configure it from a smartphone, (accessing to rpi's local web server).
I already have the web server running in raspbian and it uses some IBM watson API's in the bluemix cloud. All ok if the raspberry is connected to the internet through an AP, I can get to it's webserver and does it's external API call ok.
But when the final proyect is deployed the only thing around will be the same smartphone used to configure, so the raspberry has to get connected to the internet (tethering?) and **also** serve the local config web.
Any help or pointing in the right direction would be fantastic. 
Thank you!

Comment: This is a very wide question, it might be better to split it into two eg: connect raspberry pi to internet with smartphone tethering and access pi webserver from a phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tethering from a phone. This will enable internet access through the phone. As the hotspot/tethering on the phone is essentially a router, all you need to do to access the local config is know the ip address of the pi to access it via web browser. You can use a network scanner app on the phone to find the ip of the pi. To make sure that the pi automatically connects to the phone's hotspot on boot, start it as normal and connect to the hotspot, or use the instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)  to add the network to the file containing the saved networks. The pi has ssh enabled by default, so you can use an ssh app such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobileSSH.feng.gao&hl=en_GB) (if you are using android) and connect to the pi if you want a remote command line for configuring the pi.

Comment: A smartphone acting as an AP will normal allow you to see the IP addresses of the devices connected to it. This means you don't need to scan for the IP using a separate app.

Answer (score 0):

No, The title is not as self explanatory as you expect.

Ok let's go. you are in a no-lan/wifi network environment and you'd like to :

1°) connect your RPI to the internet using a gateway (your mobile)
2°) be able to access your web server hosted on your RPI.

assuming that's your needs , you should try to :

- setup you RPI as a hotspot (hostapd) and an internal dns (dnsmasq)
- configure a brigde on an additionnal wifi interface (usb) on your rpi to connect to your mobile gateway